# Maven keeps changing project settings - How to edit effective pom file?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I told Eclipse to use the output folder

`E:\java\<project>\<project>-parent\<project>-web-server\war\WEB-INF\classes`

but every Maven update changes it back to the value as stored in the effective pom:

```
 <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>E:\java\<project>\<project>-parent\<project>-web-server\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        <!-- .... -->
 </plugin>
```

The file is not editable and I don't really know how this file gets generated and/or how to change it. How can I manipulate the values in the effective pom file?

**Edit:**

Another thing you've already noticed are those absolute paths I'd like to get rid of. So as a side-quest: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the pom file and add the folders there. The effective POM file is, as you said, autogenerated on each build, thus also the absolute paths. In the pom file itself you of course have no absolute paths.

To change the output folder to the folder "war" in your project, add the following to your pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/war</outputDirectory>
</build>
```

You can see all configuration properties in the Maven manual: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify your maven configuration to use the desired output folder.

The effective pom you see is the "calculated" pom and hence not editable. You can edit the pom file by clicking on the pom.xml tab (just next to the effective pom tab)